# How to setup proxy host and port to IBM MQConnectionFactory

Tags: java, ibm-mq

I need to specify a custom proxy host and port for an MQConnectionFactoy and I saw that the set proxy host and port are not supported anymore. I am using exactly this 8.0 version and I don't want to downgrade.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJMSClasses/com/ibm/mq/jms/MQConnectionFactory.html#setProxyHostName(java.lang.String)

Does anyone know how I can achieve this? Is there a JmsConnectionFactoryProxy which can wrap the MQConnectionFactory?

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

C

Comment: I would like to avoid setting the proxy arguments at JVM level, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to achieve what I wanted with ProxySelector. 
I've added a custom rule for the case when scheme is "socket", hostname = "MQ_HOSTNAME" and port = "MQ_PORT" to return a custom created proxy.

```
SocketAddress socketAddress = new InetSocketAddress(proxyHost, proxyPort);
Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Type.SOCKS, socketAddress);
```